# Closing BufferedReader without closing wrapped stream

Tags: java, sockets, memory-leaks, stream

I'm currently writing a program that communicates with a server using TCP sockets. Part of that requires sending information back and forth through several methods. However, I do not want to open up a new socket connection for each request, but I can't guarantee the number or the order of the requests. In order to handle this, I simply keep one socket instance that gets reused a lot.

However, in order to read the data I use `BufferedReader` wrapper classes. Because I reuse the same socket, I can't call `close()` on the reader, or I'll close the socket stream as well.

Do I need to call `close()` on the BufferedReader if I don't want to close the underlying stream? Will I cause a memory leak by not doing this? If I do need to call `close()` how can I return the memory without closing the socket's stream?

Note: I will close the underlying stream at program termination, this question isn't about that.

Comment: Why do you want to open a new socket connection for each request?

Comment: 'Open up a new socket connection per request' and 'reuse the same socket' are mutually contradictory. Which is it? Make up your mind. And what does any of that have to do with closing a buffered reader?

Comment: Oops! Major typo there. I don't want to open a new socket per request. Edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't close the `BufferedReade`. **More important**, don't discard the `BufferedReader`; instead, pass it around rather than the `SocketInputStream`.

A `BufferedReader`, as its name implies, has an internal buffer. When you read from it, it tries to fill that buffer from the underlying `Reader`. Which means that, if you discard it, those bytes are gone.

And now some unasked advice:

- Do you really want to use a `Reader`? Most communication protocols are better implemented using a `DataInputStream`/`DataOutputStream`. With a `Reader` you're limited to character data (and in the case of `BR`, lines of character data).
- Are you paying attention to encoding? The correct way to construct a `Reader` on top of an `InputStream` is to use the two-argument variant of `InputStreamReader`: `new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8")` (you can use an encoding other than UTF-8, but [have a good reason](http://utf8everywhere.org/)).
- It's generally better to use a `BufferedInputStream` rather than a `BufferedReader`, because the translation from stream to reader may involve multiple reads. If you want `readLine()`, you can always use both.
- Be sure to close the *socket* in either a `finally` or try-with-resources. See [this](http://blog.kdgregory.com/2015/07/the-achilles-heel-of-try-with-resources.html) for more info.

Comment: Thanks this is helpful. I was kinda hoping some of that unasked advice would show up. :) I am already using the InputStreamReader, but you're right a BufferedInputStream may be better. I'll look into it.