# Why did my socket close after the handshake and how can I fix this?

Tags: java, websocket, webserver, minecraft

I am trying to connect a website to my java plugin (in minecraft) and let them communicate and play audio. When I try to send a connected message. Server starts when the plugin is enabled.

Code:
Executed when site connects to the plugin.

```
Socket client = AudioServer.getServer().accept();
            client.setKeepAlive(true);
            client.setTcpNoDelay(true);
            
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
            PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream());

            String line;
            String key = "";
            while (true) {
                line = input.readLine();
                if(line.startsWith("Sec-WebSocket-Key: ")) {
                    key = line.split(" ")[1];
                }
                if (line == null || line.isEmpty())
                    break;
            }
            output.println("HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols");
            output.println("Upgrade: websocket");
            output.println("Connection: Upgrade");
            output.println("Sec-WebSocket-Accept: " + encode(key));
            output.println();
            output.flush();
            input.close();
            
            AudioClient ac = new AudioClient(client);

    public AudioClient(Socket client) {
    try {           
        this.Client = client;
        this.conn = false;
        
        client.setKeepAlive(true);
        client.setTcpNoDelay(true);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    Thread t = new Thread(new AudioReceiver(this));
    t.start();
    
    this.sendData("connected");
}
```

Console:

```
[10:06:34] [Thread-315/WARN]: java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed
[10:06:34] [Thread-315/WARN]:   at java.net.Socket.setKeepAlive(Socket.java:1309)
[10:06:34] [Thread-315/WARN]:   at ev.Audio.AudioClient.<init>(AudioClient.java:23)
[10:06:34] [Thread-315/WARN]:   at ev.Audio.AudioConnection.run(AudioConnection.java:42)
[10:06:34] [Thread-315/WARN]:   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[10:06:34] [Thread-315/WARN]: java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed
[10:06:34] [Thread-315/WARN]:   at java.net.Socket.getOutputStream(Socket.java:943)
[10:06:34] [Thread-315/WARN]:   at ev.Audio.AudioClient.sendData(AudioClient.java:42)
[10:06:34] [Thread-315/WARN]:   at ev.Audio.AudioClient.<init>(AudioClient.java:33)
[10:06:34] [Thread-315/WARN]:   at ev.Audio.AudioConnection.run(AudioConnection.java:42)
[10:06:34] [Thread-315/WARN]:   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When closing the InputReader using `input.close();`, you also close the underlying Socket connection.

As you can see in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34946761/closing-bufferedreader-without-closing-wrapped-stream) question, you cannot close the BufferedReader without closing the Socket. Your only options would be to either pass the BufferedReader to your `AudioClient`, or to use a `DataInputStream`/`BufferedInputStream` to read the data from.